# Views not showing up on screen and image too large for screen React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

```
import React from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, View, SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native';

function WelcomeScreen(props) {
    return (

        <ImageBackground 
        style={styles.background}
        source={require("../assets/bg.jpg")}>

        <View style={styles.loginButton}></View>
        <View style={styles.registerButton}></View>

        </ImageBackground>

    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background:{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "flex-end"
    },
    loginButton:{
        width: "100%",
        height: 70,
        color: "#fc5c65"
    },
    registerButton:{
        width: "100%",
        height: 70,
        color: "#4ecdc4"
    },
})

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

This is my code so far, the 2 views with styles loginButton and registerButton are not shown on the screen and the background image is cropped and not shown completely.
I tried resizeMode="cover" as well.

I am new to React, started learning today itself.
So, please let me know what is going wrong here.

I am using expo-cli to code and debug on my Samsung NOTE 20 Ultra.

Thank you!

Comment: replace `color: "#fc5c65"` with `backgroundColor: '#fc5c65'`

Comment: @Kailash, this worked, the buttons are showing up now but still the background image is cropped

Answer (score 1):

The image isn't displaying properly, because there is probably something funky going on with the container view your are rendering the image to.

This works on my expo with an android device:

```
import React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WelcomeScreen />
    </View>
  );
}

function WelcomeScreen(props) {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      style={styles.background}
      resizeMode="cover"
      source={require("./assets/bg.jpg")}>
      <View style={styles.loginButton}></View>
      <View style={styles.registerButton}></View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
  },
  loginButton: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 70,
    backgroundColor: "#fc5c65",
  },
  registerButton: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 70,
    backgroundColor: "#4ecdc4",
  },
});
```

Comment: Changing color to background color, got me the buttons onto the screen but background image is still cropped

Comment: How is it cropped?

Comment: https://imgur.com/uTsJhBp
This is the screenshot from the phone.

Original image has full magnifying glass and a title on the left side.

Comment: Right, of course when you try to fit a horizontal image into vertical screen there will be issues. The "resizeMode" prop accepts either center, contain, cover, repeat or stretch as a value. Check if any of those gives you the desired result. https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode